# Empty array returning false when compare but when it is alone returning true...why like this

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
if([]==true) //evalutes as false
```

> //when i check empty array with true, if evaluating [] as false so it
>   if condition return false

```
if([]) //evalutes as true
```

> //when i check empty array alone, if evaluating [] as true so it if
>   condition return true

why it is evaluating like that?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [*abstract equality comparison algorithm*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) your first code will be evaluated like below,

step 1 : `ToNumber([]) == true`

step 2 : `ToPrimitive([]) == true`

(`ToNumber()` will call `ToPrimitve()` when the passed argument is an `object`)

step 3 : `"" == true`

step 4 : `0 == true`

step 5 : `false == true`

step 6 : `false`

And in your second case, `[]` is a truthy value, so `if([])` will be evaluated to true always, here `[]` will not be converted as a primitive. Abstract equality comparison algorithm comes into play when you use `==` operator.

Another better example would be,

```
var x = [] || "hello";
console.log(x); // []
```

Since `[]` is a truthy value, `x` would be set with `[]` not `"hello"`

Comment: ToPrimitive will be called if type of y is either string or number. This is basically taking last point 10. since it is satisfying neither of first 9 conditions. You gave the correct part of the spec though. +1

Comment: i dont understand one thing...why it calls ToNumber method when we are comparing with boolean?

Answer (score 0):

When you use only a variable as the condition (without comparison operators), Javascript will cast it to `Boolean` using the `Boolean()` function:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp

In your case, `Boolean([]) = true` so it returned as true.